# Promise on a server-side script (User Event) executing synchronously?

Tags: promise, netsuite, suitescript2.0

If I understood the Promise behavior correctly, it's used so that anything inside the custom Promise will be executed asynchronously.I did a test user event script and found out that it's executed synchronously.

My sample code below:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/runtime', 'N/https', 'N/url'], function (runtime, https, url) {

    function beforeLoad(context) {
        try {
            log.debug({ title: 'promise 1 start', details: new Date() });
            let promise1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
                let response = https.requestRestlet({
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    scriptId: 'customscript_test_rl',
                    deploymentId: 'customdeploy_test_rl',
                    body: JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' })
                });
                // resolve(response.body);
                log.debug({ title: 'response1', details: response });
            });
            log.debug({ title: 'promise 1 end', details: new Date() });
            log.debug({ title: 'promise 2 start', details: new Date() });
            let promise2 = new Promise((resolve) => {
                let response = https.requestRestlet({
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    scriptId: 'customscript_test_rl',
                    deploymentId: 'customdeploy_test_rl',
                    body: JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' })
                });
                // resolve(response.body);
                log.debug({ title: 'response2', details: response });
            });
            log.debug({ title: 'promise 2 end', details: new Date() });
        } catch (ex) {
            log.debug({ title: ex.name, details: ex });
        }
    }

    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad
    };
});
```

Am I doing something wrong or am I wrong about the behavior of a promise?

Comment: Hey. As long as you have this code set up what happens if you replace `let response = https.requestRestlet...` with `let response = await https.requestRestlet.promise...`.  This isn't an operation listed under https://<your ns account id>.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4387812940.html but it's a simple change in your code and it would be great  to know if it is actually supported.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I wrong about the behavior of a promise?

Yes, you are wrong.  The promise executor function is executed **synchronously**.  You don't use a promise to make something that is naturally synchronous into an asynchronous operation.  It doesn't do that.

A promise is a notification mechanism for managing and communicating the completion of an operation that is already asynchronous.  It doesn't make anything asynchronous that wasn't already asynchronous.